# How to analyze who sends me the most email

Tags: gmail, statistics

I'm trying to make the case to my small team that our email load would drop dramatically if we moved to something like slack.com. It would greatly help my case if I could have some hard data rather than anecdotal data.

Does anyone know a way to generate some basic statistics by sender for Gmail?

For instance, in this case I would like to see:

- What percentage of my email comes from sender X, Y or Z

But I would also love to know the top people I email and how often I'm sending them email, etc.

What's the best way to do this?

[Immersion from the MIT Media Lab](https://immersion.media.mit.edu/) is kind of helpful in a visual way, but I'm looking for actual stats.

Comment: @pnuts fixed. also - I'd rather find a way to automate this, since 1-100 of MANY will take a long time to scroll through, and is inaccurate because the "MANY" is conversations which may have 1-100 emails in them.

Comment: There's nothing built into Gmail for this. Have you tried searching for "[gmail analytics](https://www.google.com/search?q=gmail+analytics)"? I see a number of likely options.

Comment: I did try a google search and even tried a couple of tools but nothing I saw gave me the kind of data I'm looking for in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is if you enable [Gmail logs to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7233312) then you can run reports on these data points you're looking for.

You can also use use [GYB](https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/wiki) with [domain-wide delegation](https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/wiki#g-suite-admins-backup-restore-and-estimate-users-and-restore-to-groups) to and pull all emails from users and then find a way to query and analyse this data.